# How to get the "current" value of an Observer at subscribe-time

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm having a hard time grokking one particular part of RxJs: when you subscribe to an Observable, you're only subscribing to any *future* events from that Stream. Compare to Promises, where, if the promise has been resolved, you will get that value no matter when you call `then()`.

Here's a code example:

```js
var subject = new Rx.Subject();

subject.onNext('old value');
subject.onNext('before subscription');

subject.subscribe(function(val) {
  document.write(val);
});

subject.onNext('after subscription');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/2.3.24/rx.all.js"></script>
```

I would expect to see both "before subscription" and "after subscription" printed, although it makes sense to me that "old value" would get dropped. But it seems that RxJs doesn't work that way (only "after subscription" is printed). How can I get the result I'm after?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Rx offers both behaviors (as well as others).

The [different Rx Subjects](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/subjects.md) available can let you explore the different ways observables can behave:

- the `Rx.Subject` is the most basic fire-and-forget variety -- if you were not subscribed when the event happened, then you do not see it.
- Use `new Rx.BehaviorSubject(undefined)` instead of `Subject` and you get the behavior you were looking for, since a `BehaviorSubject` represents a "value that can change"
- Use `new Rx.ReplaySubject(5)` and you'll get the 5 most recent values as soon as you subscribe
- Use `new Rx.AsyncSubject()` and you will get nothing until the observable *completes* at which time you will get the final value (and continue to get the final value if you subscribe again).  This is the true Rx analog of Promises, since it produces nothing until it "resolves" (i.e. completes), and afterwards always gives the value to anyone that subscribes.

Comment: "Although the experienced Rx developer rarely has the need to directly create a Subject" - What do you mean by this, is there somewhere I can get more information on that?

Comment: @BenGale In most of the cases in which a developer thinks they need to create a Subject, the developer is reinventing an existing RxJs method that already exists, whether it is an observable factory that wraps an asynchronous operation, or some sort of async stream manipulation.  Not always.  Sometimes a Subject is exactly what you need.  But developers that are new to the library tend to see the Subject and reach for it first since it looks familiar and end up having a hard time because they don't realize that what they are trying to do has likely already been implemented.

Comment: @Brandon a bit off topic and late, but can you also explain "just like the experienced Promises developer rarely needs to directly create a Promise"? I happen to do this all the time, and if there's a better way of interacting with Promises, I'd like to learn it.

Comment: @EchoLogic I was referring to the [explicit construction anti-pattern](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/anti-patterns.html#the-explicit-construction-anti-pattern).  You usually only need to explicitly create Promises (or Rx Subjects) when wrapping a non-Promise-based async source.

Comment: @Brandon this says nothing about Rx. And I think if you don't create new Subjects you miss a lot. There are a lot of reasons to create Subjects to add async functionality to you application for example for communication between components while you don't want to pass states of the components around or even worse pass callback functions from one component to another.