# Angular2 Accessing first element in Observable of array

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

EDIT: I finally got my problem going in a plunk at https://plnkr.co/edit/A2WipJwW9kEhhlh90xMj.  If you hit the select market then press enter it will enter the `marketSelectorDropDown` method in the market-search.component.ts file.  The problem is in the few lines below the map and subscribe never execute until the select market dropdown is clicked again.  I do not understand why.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
this.markets
        .map(markets => {
            debugger
            if(markets && markets.length > 0) return markets[0];
        })
        .subscribe((market: Market) => {
            debugger
            this.pick(market.name)
        });
```

EDIT: In the comments of the one marked as the answer is the answer.  It is to use a BehaviorSubject.  This allows late subscribers to get the last event sent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to RxJS5 documentation

- http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-first

**First operator**

> If called with no arguments, first emits the first value of the source
>   Observable, then completes. If called with a predicate function, first
>   emits the first value of the source that matches the specified
>   condition. It may also take a resultSelector function to produce the
>   output value from the input value, and a defaultValue to emit in case
>   the source completes before it is able to emit a valid value. Throws
>   an error if defaultValue was not provided and a matching element is
>   not found.

It usefull if you deal with Observable from event

For example, emit only the first click that happens on the DOM (like `.one` in jQuery)

```
var clicks = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'click');
var result = clicks.first();
result.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Or you can look at other use case in this answer [Angular 2 runOutsideAngular still change the UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40300635/angular-2-runoutsideangular-still-change-the-ui/40301972#40301972)

So it isn't exactly that what you want, but you can use it like this:

```
.first(null, arr => arr[0]).subscribe...
```

and it should return desired first element of array **[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/G1JhP69JxBZb1eIROVZ6?p=preview)**(first)

But i would leverage `map` operator to do the same:

```
.map(arr => arr[0]).subscribe...
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/4sWP5qJ6RmGb8JHxrXr4?p=preview)**(map)

Comment: When I try: `        this.markets
            .first(null, markets => markets[0])
            .subscribe((market: Market) => {
                this.pick(market.name)
            });
` and set a breakpoint in the subscribe method it is never hit.

Comment: Angular2 uses rxjs5. I added plunker. There is dummy json and it always returns `name1`

Comment: I really appreciate your example and I see how it works now, but when I take your code and apply it to mine it doesn't work.  I don't understand why.  Do you have any thoughts?  I've included the entire ts file this time in my question.

Comment: I got my problem in a [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/A2WipJwW9kEhhlh90xMj?p=preview) The problem is as I have restated above the map and subscribe never fire until a new searchTerm is added to the subject.

Comment: Observables are lazy. Try to subscribe before emitting event https://plnkr.co/edit/4Oo5WZzjL6b7O8SV6IFj?p=preview

Comment: In your plunk the subscrbe never fires.  I want to be able to retrieve the first item in that drop down list when the user presses enter.  The list could filtered by text entered into the box.

Comment: It fires but in your case maybe you're looking for BehaviorSubject https://plnkr.co/edit/WEMAkwvUHtpKnO38CWpJ?p=preview See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28311118/how-to-get-the-current-value-of-an-observer-at-subscribe-time

Comment: the BehaviorSubject is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I was able to access the Observable's first member by using angular's async pipe.

yourComponent.html 
    (yourObservable | async | slice :0:1)

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't work because you are using CDN for RxJS 2, You need RxJS 5 for this.
I tried to replace the CDN to version 5 and it was working just fine.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I realize not I was using wrong version in example, but I am still unable to get it to work in my real world situation.

Comment: In your Markup, try to use: (keydown.enter), no capital letters.

Comment: the casing of the event is not the problem.  the event fires as you can in this [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/A2WipJwW9kEhhlh90xMj?p=preview).  The problem is as I have restated above the map and subscribe never fire until a new searchTerm is added to the subject.